Finding the coordinate of center of mass by revolving
In my recent class, I was taught a new method to find the coordinate of the center of mass of a body.
For example, a uniform semi-circular disk, if revolved by its diameter, creates a solid sphere whose volume is $\dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3$, we can see that the center of mass translated by $2 \pi y$, where $y$ is the distance of the center of mass from the axis.
Then, if it were to move in a line instead of a circle, it would have made a shape of volume $2 \pi y \cdot \dfrac{\pi r^2}{2}$
and equating the volume, we get $y=\dfrac{4r}{3 \pi}$.
I have tried this for a hemisphere also, and it works if we consider the shape formed to be a 4D ball.
If anyone can source this from any book or other it will be a great help, as I am trying to find out more about this type of thinking and approach.
any thing that might motivate this type of approach will help.

thx Bml for the edit

A drawing would be very helpful - it is a little hard to follow your example

Did you ask your teacher why this method works?

@AbC You are welcome!

It is an application of Pappus's Centroid Theorem with a nice animation and also look at Feynman 19–2 Locating the center of mass.

@PM2Ring he said that since the COM is the point that only translate the volume/area of both shapes must be same

Thx @Farcher for pointing out pappus's theorem

You should [edit] that info into your question.
